# Xpath doesn't work with string, which have quotes. Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, quotes

I have the text:
`var1 = 'ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"'`

And I have xpath:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='"+var1+"']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']").click()` - It does'nt work

`//a[text()='ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']` - But this work!

Python writes me :`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']"}`

But if I Cut xpath from error messeage and put it like xpath in console of Chrome - element would finded.

Element absoulutle visible and already loaded.
Sory for my English.

Comment: you need to properly escape the quote marks. Your question/code is a bit tough to read so I can't give exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes. Try either this:

```
var1 = 'ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"'

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()=\''+var1+'\']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,\'chakra-stack\') and contains(@class,\'css-1oap1wr\')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()=\'Отклонить\']').click()
```

or this

```
var1 = 'ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"'

#replace the double quotes with \"
var1 = var1.replace('"', '\\"')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='"+var1+"']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']").click()
```

Comment: I did it, and it doesn't work too. If I replace " on \" in xpath it looks like \"

Comment: I don't understand your comment.